# What do the square bracket signify in $\int [\text{d}\pi]f(\pi)$

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, notation, field-theory, dirac-delta

I am reading [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/037026938791197X) which repeatedly includes integrals such as,

$$
P_M(\phi \to \phi')
   =
   \int [\text{d}\pi][\text{d}\pi']
            P_G(\pi)\delta((\phi, \pi) - (\phi'', \pi''))
$$

Note that $P_G$ is a probability and $\pi$ is a momentum not $3.14\dots$ also note that $\delta(x)$ is the dirac delta function.

The integral is defined over phase space on a lattice. $\phi$ is some field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very likely that they mean the floor function $\lfloor x \rfloor$, which yields the largest integer less than $x$. This seems even more likely as this has to do with estimates over lattices, and so should be discretized.

Then these integrals should be interpreted as [Riemann-Stieltjes Integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral).

Comment: After reading the link and a few papers. Yes, I agree this makes sense.

Comment: @AlexanderMcFarlane Good! And good luck.

Comment: Thanks! What I thought was a simple paper has led me to fibre bundles, hellishly complex pure maths and now this strange integral. I am just glad it's not that complex in this case!